# Bind Python turtle exitonclick() function to another key

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I am using Python 2.7 turtle graphics to make a simple mouse sensor that draws whenever you hold down the mouse button. Since my function is based on the user, it crashes right when you run it. I found out that `turtle.exitonclick()` will help keep the interface on, but I can't draw because my draw is bound to the left mouse button click. Is there any solution to get around this or is it possible to rebind `turtle.exitonclick()` to something else? Here's my code:

```
import turtle


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightblue")

#wn.screensize(400,300)
turtle.setup(400,300)

draw = turtle.Turtle()

def gothere(event):
    draw.penup()
    draw.goto(event.x-360, 340-event.y)
    draw.pendown()
    #draw.color(blue)

def movearound(event):
    draw.goto(event.x-360, 340-event.y)
    draw.color(blue)

def release(event):
    draw.penup()

def reset(event):
    draw.clear()

cavset = turtle.getcanvas()

cavset.bind("<Button-2>", gothere)
cavset.bind("<B1-Motion>", movearound)
cavset.bind("<ButtonRelease-2>", release)
cavset.bind("<Escape>", reset)

wn.listen()
wn.exitonclick()
```

(I am running through command prompt, BTW.)

Comment: Do not paste code as images!  ... it is FAR more helpful to use the `{}` to add code in the textarea of your question, so that others can copy/paste and actually TRY you code. You will likely get downvoted due to that, but none will be mine.

Answer (score 0):

What you most likely want is:

```
turtle.mainloop()
```

instead of:

```
wn.exitonclick()
```

as that's what `exitonclick()` calls after setting up a handler for the "onclick" part.

However, there are other issues.  You seem to be mixing three different coding models: functional interface to turtle; object-oriented interface to turtle; calling into turtle's Tkinter underpinnings.

Let's simplify and just use the object-oriented interface to turtle:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, mainloop

def gothere(x, y):
    draw.penup()
    draw.goto(x, y)
    draw.pendown()

def movearound(x, y):
    draw.ondrag(None)  # disable handler in handler!
    draw.color("blue")
    draw.goto(x, y)
    draw.ondrag(movearound)

def release(x, y):
    draw.penup()

def reset():
    draw.clear()

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(400, 300)
wn.bgcolor("lightblue")

draw = Turtle()

wn.onclick(gothere, 2)

draw.ondrag(movearound)
draw.onrelease(release, 2)

wn.onkey(reset, "Escape")
wn.listen()

mainloop()
```

I believe Python 3 turtle tweaks the turtle event interface to add some methods and use clearer names for others.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. The window did stay but idk whether it's because I'm using 2.7 but I did run into an error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 699, in eventfun
    fun(x, y)
TypeError: gothere() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @AndrewXu, did you copy my code exactly?  It sounds like you're using your old Tkinter `gothere(event)` instead of my turtle `gothere(x, y)`.